# seekg doesn't work when use 'sizeof()' with ios::end

Tags: c++, file-io, turbo-c++

I was trying to read the last entry of a binary file containing structures.
(I'm working on Turboc++ because my school uses it to teach us)

I tried doing `seekg(-sizeof(info),ios::end)` , where `info` is the structure, but it doesn't give me the desired output.
But when i do `seekg(-4,ios::end)` , (`info` is of size 4) it works fine.
Even `seekg(sizeof(info),ios::beg)` works fine (Did that to check if I'm using sizeof() in the wrong way)

The following program (which I wrote on turboc++) demonstrates the problem I'm facing (though it's not the actual program I'm working on)

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>

struct info{
int age, num;
};

int main()
{
info p1,p2;
ofstream fout("NEWF",ios::out|ios::binary|ios::trunc);
ifstream fin;

p1.num=2; p1.age=20;
fout.write((char*)&p1,sizeof(info));

p1.num=4; p1.age=20;
fout.write((char*)&p1,sizeof(info));

fout.close();

fin.open("NEWF",ios::in|ios::binary);
fin.seekg(-sizeof(info),ios::end); //trying to access last entry
// int nsize= -sizeof(info);
// fin.seekg(nsize,ios::end); <--- This works
fin.read((char*)&p2,sizeof(info));

cout<<p2.num<<"  "<<p2.age;
return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is: **1532  1556** ,
While the expected output is : **4  20**

I did go through many similar questions already asked by people related to seekg() but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: GCC is a free compiler (chain). You should ditch that Turbo C++ abomination.

Comment: *I'm working on Turboc++ because my school uses it to teach us)* -- how to not be C++ programmers in the modern world.

Comment: our school uses turboc++ to teavh us, can't help it

Comment: @Utkarsh *<-- This works (size of info is 4)* -- Where is your proof of this?  Where did you actually output `sizeof(info)` to verify this claim?

Comment: I know right? My teacher is crazy

Comment: @Utkarsh If you are stuck in an education system that imposes turboc++, it's *vital* that you supplement your education with personal projects using a proper modern commercially viable compiler.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm sorry. I did that in some test runs. I edited my program in the question.

Comment: @Utkarsh -- Please output `cout << -sizeof(info)`.  Don't be shocked by what you see.  `sizeof()` returns an unsigned value, and you're negating it.  That can only lead to trouble.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  I do try to do that in whatever little time I get from doing the useless projects my school gives us

Comment: @Utkarsh -- Also, if you claim that `-4` works, but `-sizeof(info)` doesn't, then that should have prompted you to do more research into why `-sizeof(info)` is returning something that doesn't equal `-4`.  Outputting `-sizeof(info)` directly may have given you a hint on what is happening.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I get 65532 . But why? And when I use `seekg(int(-sizeof(info)),ios::end)` , my program works fine. (just thought of typecasting to int because using `nsize` worked and it does type cast to int )

Comment: @Utkarsh -- Your compiler is weak.  It should have warned you about the unsigned / signed conversion going on.  Time to read up on how unsigned and signed integers are stored.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you so much. I didn't expect `-sizeof(info)` to take such values and so I didn't check if it takes the value -4 or not. I'll be careful next time.

Comment: @Utkarsh -- Since I do not have (or want) Turbo C++, I suggest you read the documentation carefully for the `seekg()` function.  What is the type for the first argument?  Is it an unsigned int, or just int?  If it's unsigned, that explains what is going on.  You told `seekg()` to go to position 65532.